# How to disable autolinking on iOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I've installed react-native-localization in my react native project (v0.6). Library is not supporting autolinker yet so I need to disable it for iOS and Android in react-native.config.js.

I already tried to add dependencies in react-native.config.js. After that, I did `react-native link react-native-localization` command and build an app.

This is my react-native.config.js file:

```
'use strict';

const ios = require('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios');
const android = require('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android');

module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-localization': {
      platforms: {
        android: null, // disable Android platform, other platforms will still autolink if provided
        ios: null,
      },
    },
  },
  commands: [...ios.commands, ...android.commands],
  platforms: {
    ios: {
      linkConfig: ios.linkConfig,
      projectConfig: ios.projectConfig,
      dependencyConfig: ios.dependencyConfig,
    },
    android: {
      linkConfig: android.linkConfig,
      projectConfig: android.projectConfig,
      dependencyConfig: android.dependencyConfig,
    },
  },
  /**
   * Used when running RNTester (with React Native from source)
   */
  reactNativePath: '.',
  project: {
    ios: {
      project: './RNTester/RNTester.xcodeproj',
    },
    android: {
      sourceDir: './RNTester',
    },
  },
};
```

Error in simulator says: 
"Please check your configuration. Did you run 'react-native link'?

Comment: did you try also do `cd ios` and `pod install`?

Comment: Thank you so much. Where could I find information about it? Yesterday, I spend like 3h to make it work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As now, react-native has added the support for CocoaPods inside of his projects. (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases)

Sadly, i don't know why, but the autolinking feature never works for me on iOS but always goes trough in Android. The only solution i found is to do a react-native link only for iOS (renaming the android folder to something else), then do `cd ios` and `pod install`. After that, in the majority of the cases, it would work out of the box, while other libs needs still to be updated to have a full integration with RN 0.60.

Hope all this will be fixed soon but until that we only have to wait and hope that the libs work without any other complications